# Can we keep the AppDelegate swift file when upgrading from React Native 0.66.4 to 0.69.6

Tags: c++, ios, swift, react-native

We are upgrading a react native project from 0.66.4 to 0.69.6.

The project uses an `AppDelegate.swift` file but the react native upgrade helper uses the `AppDelegate.m` class in its upgrade example and instructs to delete it and replace it with a `AppDelegate.mm` class. See [Upgrade helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.66.4&to=0.69.6)

To my understanding this allows the compiler to compile C and C++ code.

My question is how do we keep the logic in our AppDelegate swift class? Do we have to use the AppDelegate.mm and integrate the swift code into it or is there a better way?

Content from `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Adyen
import GoogleCast
import Didomi
import os
import FBSDKCoreKit

#if DEBUG
// #if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
import FlipperKit
// #endif
#endif

@UIApplicationMain

  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, RCTBridgeDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate,
  UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager {

  private func initializeFlipper(with application: UIApplication) {
    #if DEBUG
    // Check if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED  and commented pluggins work in RN 0.67+ versions
    // #if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
    let client = FlipperClient.shared()
    let layoutDescriptorMapper = SKDescriptorMapper(defaults: ())
    // FlipperKitLayoutComponentKitSupport.setUpWith(layoutDescriptorMapper)
    client?.add(FlipperKitLayoutPlugin(rootNode: application, with: layoutDescriptorMapper!))
    client?.add(FKUserDefaultsPlugin(suiteName: nil))
    client?.add(FlipperKitReactPlugin())
    client?.add(FlipperKitNetworkPlugin(networkAdapter: SKIOSNetworkAdapter()))
    // client?.add(FlipperReactPerformancePlugin.sharedInstance())
    client?.start()
    // #endif
    #endif
  }

  func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! {
    #if DEBUG
      return RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings()?.jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource: nil)
    #else
      return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")
    #endif
  }

  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  var orientationLock: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
  var rootView: RCTRootView?
  var isScreenRecordingEnabled: Bool?
  var isCaptured: Bool?
  public weak var authorizationFlowManagerDelegate: RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManagerDelegate?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
   
    _ = localizedString(LocalizationKey(key: "adyen.card.expiryItem.title"), nil)

    //  Start screen recording in a disabled state
    isScreenRecordingEnabled = false
    let config = ReactNativeConfig.env()!
    WonderPush.setClientId((config["WONDERPUSH_CLIENT_ID"] as? String)!,
                           secret: (config["WONDERPUSH_CLIENT_SECRET"] as? String)!)
    WonderPush.setupDelegateForUserNotificationCenter()
    WonderPush.setRequiresUserConsent(false)
    WonderPush.setUserConsent(true)

    return true
  }
  // swiftlint:disable block_based_kvo
  // swiftlint:disable colon
  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?,
                             change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                             context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      if keyPath == "captured" {
        isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
        if !isScreenRecordingEnabled! {
          if isCaptured! {
            rootView?.isHidden = true
          }
          if !isCaptured! && rootView?.isHidden == true {
            rootView?.isHidden = false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // swiftlint:disable force_cast
    launchDidomi(apiKey: ReactNativeConfig.env()!["DIDOMI_API_KEY"] as! String)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    initializeFlipper(with: application)

    let receiverAppID = kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID // or "ABCD1234"
    let criteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: receiverAppID)
    let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
    GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = true

    self.bridge = RCTBridge(delegate: self, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    guard let bridge = self.bridge else {
      return false
    }

    let props: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
      "APP_INFO": (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["APP_INFO"] as? String) ?? "",
      "VERSION": (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]) ?? ""
    ]

    rootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "PSG", initialProperties: props)

    rootView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 33.0/255.0, blue: 45.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    RNSplashScreen.show()

    WonderPush.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)

    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.disableScreenRecording(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("DisableScreenRecording"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.enableScreenRecording(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("EnableScreenRecording"), object: nil)
    return true
  }

  private func launchDidomi(apiKey: String) {
    Didomi.shared.setLogLevel(minLevel: OSLogType.info.rawValue)

    Didomi.shared.initialize(
      apiKey: apiKey,
      localConfigurationPath: nil,
      remoteConfigurationURL: nil,
      providerId: nil,
      disableDidomiRemoteConfig: false
    )
  }

  @objc func disableScreenRecording(notification: NSNotification) {
    isScreenRecordingEnabled = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if self.isCaptured ?? false {
        self.rootView?.isHidden = true
      }
    }
  }
  @objc func enableScreenRecording(notification: NSNotification) {
    isScreenRecordingEnabled = true
  }
  func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
      restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void
  ) -> Bool {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app step 6
    let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()
      .handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in
        _ = dynamiclink
        _ = error
        // no-op
      }

    return handled || RCTLinkingManager.application(
        application,
        continue: userActivity,
        restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
  }
  
  func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                   open url: URL,
                   options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app step 7
    if DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) != nil {
     
      return true
    }

    RCTLinkingManager.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options) {
      return true
    }
    // swiftlint:enable colon
    if Adyen.RedirectComponent.applicationDidOpen(from: url) { return true }

    return authorizationFlowManagerDelegate?.resumeExternalUserAgentFlow(with: url) ?? false
  }

  // swiftlint:disable colon
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // swiftlint:enable colon
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: error)
  }

  // swiftlint:disable colon
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // swiftlint:enable colon
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo,
                           fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    WonderPush.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    WonderPush.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return orientationLock
  }
}
```

How would an `AppDelegate.mm` file that includes this functionality would look like?

Comment: If you have an `AppDelegate.swift` file youre probably not using the `AppDelegate.m` implementation. Without knowing whats in your `AppDelegate.swift` its hard to suggest what to do. But generally, I'd recommend using the provided `AppDelegate.mm` and make your `AppDelegate.swift` an extension and override any relevant methods.

Comment: @mani I have added the content of my swift file. A solution to enable the new architecture for that file will be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Are you using / planning to use `Fabric`? If not, you shouldn't need to make any changes to your `AppDelegate.swift`. In your app delegate, you're manually creating a react bridge and setting up the root view controller. Have you tried the upgrade? Did things break? It *should* just work. Also, the `AppDelegate.mm` is in `RnDiffApp` - which is the react native diff app to highlight any changes, and its not used in your case. Just do the upgrade - things shouldn't break. Then add Fabric support to your `AppDelegate.swift`

Comment: @mani, yes we're planning to use Fabric. We have tried the update, things didn't break, (with no support for Fabric). We would like to see how the Fabric support would look like in our swift file if possible or if that is not possible how our AppDelegate.swift could be converted to mm file. We are wondering if new RN architecture recommends `mm` instead of `swift` and why they haven't included any solution using `swift` in their docs.

Comment: are you using any C++ code? @Solly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native is experimenting with a new rendering system written in c++. C++ is not directly usable via Swift - and thats why they're recommending using `.mm` file. `.mm` file is an Objective c++ file which can have c++ code in it. Using Objective c++ is one way to bridge c++ code to Swift (the other is to write a C wrapper). So to initialize Fabric you need to have the AppDelegate written in objective c++.

If you prefer to work in swift, then we can write a base class in objective c++, and override relevant methods in swift. Something like this should work.

Add a new file: `AppDelegateBase.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegateBase : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

- (NSDictionary *)prepareInitialProps;

@end
```

Add another new file: `AppDelegateBase.mm` - (Based on AppDelegate.mm from react diff project)

```
#import "AppDelegateBase.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>

static NSString *const kRNConcurrentRoot = @"concurrentRoot";

@interface AppDelegateBase () <RCTCxxBridgeDelegate, RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate> {
  RCTTurboModuleManager *_turboModuleManager;
  RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter *_bridgeAdapter;
  std::shared_ptr<const facebook::react::ReactNativeConfig> _reactNativeConfig;
  facebook::react::ContextContainer::Shared _contextContainer;
}
@end
#endif

@implementation AppDelegateBase

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  _contextContainer = std::make_shared<facebook::react::ContextContainer const>();
  _reactNativeConfig = std::make_shared<facebook::react::EmptyReactNativeConfig const>();
  _contextContainer->insert("ReactNativeConfig", _reactNativeConfig);
  _bridgeAdapter = [[RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter alloc] initWithBridge:bridge contextContainer:_contextContainer];
  bridge.surfacePresenter = _bridgeAdapter.surfacePresenter;
#endif

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

/// This method controls whether the `concurrentRoot`feature of React18 is turned on or off.
///
/// @see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html
/// @note: This requires to be rendering on Fabric (i.e. on the New Architecture).
/// @return: `true` if the `concurrentRoot` feture is enabled. Otherwise, it returns `false`.
- (BOOL)concurrentRootEnabled
{
  // Switch this bool to turn on and off the concurrent root
  return true;
}

- (NSDictionary *)prepareInitialProps
{
  NSMutableDictionary *initProps = [NSMutableDictionary new];

#ifdef RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  initProps[kRNConcurrentRoot] = @([self concurrentRootEnabled]);
#endif

  return initProps;
}

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED

#pragma mark - RCTCxxBridgeDelegate

- (std::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>)jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  _turboModuleManager = [[RCTTurboModuleManager alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                             delegate:self
                                                            jsInvoker:bridge.jsCallInvoker];
  return RCTAppSetupDefaultJsExecutorFactory(bridge, _turboModuleManager);
}

#pragma mark RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate

- (Class)getModuleClassFromName:(const char *)name
{
  return RCTCoreModulesClassProvider(name);
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                      jsInvoker:(std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::CallInvoker>)jsInvoker
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                     initParams:
                                                         (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (id<RCTTurboModule>)getModuleInstanceFromClass:(Class)moduleClass
{
  return RCTAppSetupDefaultModuleFromClass(moduleClass);
}

#endif

@end
```

Update your `AppDelegate.swift`.. Have marked the changes with `>>>`.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Adyen
import GoogleCast
import Didomi
import os
import FBSDKCoreKit

#if DEBUG
// #if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
import FlipperKit
// #endif
#endif

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: AppDelegateBase, // >>> subclassing base class 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, 
RCTBridgeDelegate, 
RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManager {

  private func initializeFlipper(with application: UIApplication) {
    #if DEBUG
    // Check if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED  and commented pluggins work in RN 0.67+ versions
    // #if FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
    let client = FlipperClient.shared()
    let layoutDescriptorMapper = SKDescriptorMapper(defaults: ())
    // FlipperKitLayoutComponentKitSupport.setUpWith(layoutDescriptorMapper)
    client?.add(FlipperKitLayoutPlugin(rootNode: application, with: layoutDescriptorMapper!))
    client?.add(FKUserDefaultsPlugin(suiteName: nil))
    client?.add(FlipperKitReactPlugin())
    client?.add(FlipperKitNetworkPlugin(networkAdapter: SKIOSNetworkAdapter()))
    // client?.add(FlipperReactPerformancePlugin.sharedInstance())
    client?.start()
    // #endif
    #endif
  }

  func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! {
    #if DEBUG
      return RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings()?.jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index", fallbackResource: nil)
    #else
      return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")
    #endif
  }

  // var window: UIWindow? // >>> window created in Base class
  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  var orientationLock: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait
  var rootView: RCTRootView?
  var isScreenRecordingEnabled: Bool?
  var isCaptured: Bool?
  public weak var authorizationFlowManagerDelegate: RNAppAuthAuthorizationFlowManagerDelegate?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
   
    _ = localizedString(LocalizationKey(key: "adyen.card.expiryItem.title"), nil)

    //  Start screen recording in a disabled state
    isScreenRecordingEnabled = false
    let config = ReactNativeConfig.env()!
    WonderPush.setClientId((config["WONDERPUSH_CLIENT_ID"] as? String)!,
                           secret: (config["WONDERPUSH_CLIENT_SECRET"] as? String)!)
    WonderPush.setupDelegateForUserNotificationCenter()
    WonderPush.setRequiresUserConsent(false)
    WonderPush.setUserConsent(true)

    return true
  }
  // swiftlint:disable block_based_kvo
  // swiftlint:disable colon
  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?,
                             change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                             context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      if keyPath == "captured" {
        isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
        if !isScreenRecordingEnabled! {
          if isCaptured! {
            rootView?.isHidden = true
          }
          if !isCaptured! && rootView?.isHidden == true {
            rootView?.isHidden = false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // >>> important to call super.application(_, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) that is in AppDelegateBase **
    super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    // swiftlint:disable force_cast
    launchDidomi(apiKey: ReactNativeConfig.env()!["DIDOMI_API_KEY"] as! String)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    initializeFlipper(with: application)

    let receiverAppID = kGCKDefaultMediaReceiverApplicationID // or "ABCD1234"
    let criteria = GCKDiscoveryCriteria(applicationID: receiverAppID)
    let options = GCKCastOptions(discoveryCriteria: criteria)
    GCKCastContext.setSharedInstanceWith(options)
    GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = true

    self.bridge = RCTBridge(delegate: self, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    guard let bridge = self.bridge else {
      return false
    }
    // >>> props created from AppDelegateBase
    var props: [AnyHashable: Any] = prepareInitialProps()
    props["APP_INFO"] = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["APP_INFO"] as? String) ?? ""
    props["VERSION"]: (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"]) ?? ""

    rootView = RCTRootView(bridge: bridge, moduleName: "PSG", initialProperties: props)

    rootView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 22.0/255.0, green: 33.0/255.0, blue: 45.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    
    // >>> self.window is created in AppDelegateBase
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    RNSplashScreen.show()

    WonderPush.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)

    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.disableScreenRecording(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("DisableScreenRecording"), object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.enableScreenRecording(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("EnableScreenRecording"), object: nil)
    return true
  }

  private func launchDidomi(apiKey: String) {
    Didomi.shared.setLogLevel(minLevel: OSLogType.info.rawValue)

    Didomi.shared.initialize(
      apiKey: apiKey,
      localConfigurationPath: nil,
      remoteConfigurationURL: nil,
      providerId: nil,
      disableDidomiRemoteConfig: false
    )
  }

  @objc func disableScreenRecording(notification: NSNotification) {
    isScreenRecordingEnabled = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if self.isCaptured ?? false {
        self.rootView?.isHidden = true
      }
    }
  }
  @objc func enableScreenRecording(notification: NSNotification) {
    isScreenRecordingEnabled = true
  }
  func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
      restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void
  ) -> Bool {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app step 6
    let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks()
      .handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { dynamiclink, error in
        _ = dynamiclink
        _ = error
        // no-op
      }

    return handled || RCTLinkingManager.application(
        application,
        continue: userActivity,
        restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
  }
  
  func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                   open url: URL,
                   options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app step 7
    if DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) != nil {
     
      return true
    }

    RCTLinkingManager.application(app, open: url, options: options)
    if ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options) {
      return true
    }
    // swiftlint:enable colon
    if Adyen.RedirectComponent.applicationDidOpen(from: url) { return true }

    return authorizationFlowManagerDelegate?.resumeExternalUserAgentFlow(with: url) ?? false
  }

  // swiftlint:disable colon
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // swiftlint:enable colon
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: error)
  }

  // swiftlint:disable colon
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // swiftlint:enable colon
    WonderPush.application(application,
                           didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo,
                           fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    WonderPush.applicationDidBecomeActive(application)
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    WonderPush.applicationDidEnterBackground(application)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return orientationLock
  }
}
```

This should automatically create a Bridging header for your project.
Add this to your bridging header:

```
#include "AppDelegateBase.h"
```

Comment: Great thank you. This helped, I had to make a few small changes but it worked!

Comment: @ mani Thanks for the code snippets!


@Solly What are the changes you had to do? I’m trying to perform a similar thing and still have some issues.

Comment: @mani Can you please guide me, How can I access the Swift Singleton class function in AppDelegate.mm file?

Comment: @AbhishekR can you please ask a new question. Is the Swift method you're trying to call part of UIApplicationDelegate or is it one you define? If its part of UIApplicationDelegate, it should be accessible in objc already, if its one you define, you can either use a sendMessage to objc call, or look into how to bridge swift to objc here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/importing-swift-into-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

As per react native doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/new-architecture-app-intro

TurboModules can be written using Objective-C or C++. In order to support both cases, any source files that include C++ code should use the .mm file extension. This extension corresponds to Objective-C++, a language variant that allows for the use of a combination of C++ and Objective-C in source files.

Read all doc related to iOS carefully

AND

Implement this method in swift

```
#pragma mark - RCTCxxBridgeDelegate

    - (std::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>)jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
    {
      return std::make_unique<facebook::react::HermesExecutorFactory>(facebook::react::RCTJSIExecutorRuntimeInstaller([bridge](facebook::jsi::Runtime &runtime) {
          if (!bridge) {
            return;
          }
        })
      );
    }
```

Make sure to mark above method as @objc method

Comment: I am not a master in React Native but my suggestion is to use Objective-C for native iOS code while developing an app in React Native as React Native uses Objective-C. So you will get better and faster support with Objective-C
Ref - https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/bof192/objc_or_swift_to_complement_react_native/